# A group of related Aggregates inside a bounded context

Tags: domain-driven-design

In the Vaughn Vernon red book sample project https://github.com/VaughnVernon/IDDD_Samples he organized the project in this way:

- Bounded Context (1) 
  ---- "Layers" or "Hexagonal areas" (1.1) 
  -------- **A group of related aggregates  (1.1.1)**  
  ----------- Agreggates and related entities and value objects 
  -------- **Other group of related aggregates (1.1.1)**  
  ----------- Agreggates and related entities and value objects

For example:

- iddd_agilepm (1) 
  ---- application (1.1) 
  ------- ... 
  ------- domain (1.1) 
  ---------- ... 
  ---------- **product (1.1.1)** 
  ------------- product aggregate and related entities and value objects 
  ------------- release 
  ---------------- release aggregate and related entities and value objects 
  ------------- sprint 
  ---------------- sprint aggregate and related entities and value objects 
  ------------- backlogitem 
  ---------------- backlogitem aggregate and related entities and value objects 
  ---------- ... 
  ----- ports/adapters (1.1) 
  -------- ...
- iddd_collaboration

**Is there a formal definition to "A group of related aggregates" inside a bounded context?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a formal definition to "A group of related aggregates" inside a bounded context?

[No](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Cunningham%27s_Law).  There is no standardized language that describes a group of related aggregates that is smaller than "bounded context".

The closest language I have seen is Udi Dahan's use of "autonomous component"; his example was something like a sales context, where you might have one business policy for your low volume customers and a completely different policy for your high volume "premium" customers.  So we're serving the same business capability, but using different implementations to provide that capability.

But, as far as I can tell, it's "accidentally similar" to the sort of cluster of aggregates that you are thinking about, but not actually a match.